# Python subprocess is unstable on Windows 10?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen([executable_file])
```

This is only code that I am using to run the python subprocess. However, it has unknown issue that cause my program cannot open the executable file as expected.

`executable_file` is one file link (PATH) that locate executable program.

Ex. `C:\Users\SharkIng\Dev\WhatEverSystem\Builds\Windows\program-123456789-123456789.exe`

The python `subprocess.Popen` should run the program. However, sometime it works and sometime it is not (I did not change any code between this two situation)

OS: Windows 10
Python: 2.7.*

Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

**BUT:** It is working if you manually run `subprocess.Popen([executable_file_path_string])` (with same file and path) it work.

WHY this happen?? Is that because some problem with Windows Python? or it is because my setting mess me up?

**UPDATE:** It is not some reason such as *NOT FULL PATH*. I can have it working with exact same code. If I ran same code in a python shell, by typing each line of code. It works. But if I put exact same code in a `.py` file and run it with `python file.py`, it showing the error

**UPDATE 2:** Another team member have same error with Windows 7 and Python 2.7.* This code used to work this morning. **AGAIN** I didn't change anything. That is way I am asking if it is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with `subprocess`. If you want to run a specified executable, you need to give the full path to that file. The most likely reason you're seeing variable behavior is that sometimes you're in the directory with the `.exe`, and other times you're not.

Comment: It is Full path, `executable_file` variable is equal to `'C:\Users\SharkIng\Dev\WhatEverSystem\Builds\Windows\program-123456789-123456789.exe'`. I can make it work when i am in python shell and type each line of my code one by one, but its is not working when i ran `python test.py`.